# Connect TSOP to prolifc serial

Tags: usb, serial, infrared

I have a prolifc USB to serial cable that I want to use to recieve infrared signals coming from a TSOP Sensor

I saw it is possible to connect a classic rs232 connector with TSOP [here](http://www.voti.nl/ir-2/index_1.html).

How can I connect it without damaging something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most probably can't do that. The standard software for a TSOP-RS232 combo relies on the ability to read the hardware serial port very fast. An usb-to-serial cable does not offfer this option, it only offers a windows serial port interface, not the serial port hardware (register level) interface.

One option is to have a microcontroller read out the TSOP and send the decoded information to the PC, like shown [here](http://www.ocinside.de/go_e.html?http://www.ocinside.de/html/modding/usb_ir_receiver/usb_ir_receiver.html).